# Connecting mySQL db through PHP

Tags: mysql, database, user-registration, login-control

Let me begin by saying I am extremely new at this. I am trying to develop a mobile app and a website with no real experience. There is likely something that I have missed or I am doing wrong but I cannot seem to pin point where the issue is. Prior to creating my own, I followed a video guide (with the demo files downloaded to my computer) but cannot seem to connect to my database. I have also copied the demo files and placed them into my code and it is still getting me caught on one section. I am using the program MAMP for the connection and Brackets for the code. Below are my session files:

**Database connection**-

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "root";
$dbName = "Login System";

$con = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

**My sign up document**-

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //Error handlers
    //Check for empty fields
    if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        echo <h2>Please fill in all fields;
        exit ();
    } else {
        //Check if input characters are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
            exit();
        } else {
            //Check if email is valid
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    //Hashing the password
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    //Insert the user into the database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, uid, pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

**My Login Sheet**

```
    <?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>

    <section class="main-container">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <h2>Signup</h2>
            <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Firstname">
                <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Lastname">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <Button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</Button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </section>

<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

I have reset the password for 'root' to 'root' and ensured I can login with that. The document that checks for error's lists if any field is empty, return to the previous page with the word "=empty" in the url. No matter what I type into my fields, it is either not pushing the information into the database or I have incorrectly mapped my fields so one of the database fields is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As I said at the beginning of this post, I am extremely new at this. You may see something that is incredibly obvious and somewhat dumb... you've been warned! I am working on creating a mobile application and website that allows users to login. The login attempt will reference my localhost database to confirm that the user does not exist or that the user is not in use.

Thank you!

Comment: At least one issue: perhaps a variable mismatch?  I see in your db connection there is `$con`, but when attempted to be used at the escape functions and the query, there is `$conn` (an extra 'n').

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look. I did try it with $conn and that did not work either. I tested with $con and it didn’t work but I forgot to change it back.

Comment: Are you sure that the connection is successful?  Make the program help you find what is wrong. Try adding this after the connect (or after the include line):  `if ( !$conn ) { echo 'Did not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); }` ... make sure to change `$con` back to `$conn` first.

Comment: I added that information into the script. Very strange.. I spent 10 hours (total) yesterday and could not get past the first or second error check. This time, however, it moved me through the entire process and I received "success" in the URL. I checked the database that I have it pointed to and there are no new users added in there.

Although I am extremely new at this, I feel like it could have something to do with the way my database is built to add users and how I have coded the users to be added (if that makes sense). Lastly, I have 3 tables in one of the databases. I don't see the code

Comment: That tells it which table to enter the information into, only the database that the information is being sent to.

Comment: So, are you saying that the connection is working, but no users are inserted?  Also, I don't know what you mean by "I don't see the code"?

Comment: Yes, my apologies on the verbiage. The check was error free but no user was inserted into the database.

Comment: Ok, then try this after the first query:  `if (false === $result) { echo 'Query error: ' . mysqli_error($conn); }`  ... if the first one does OK, then do the same for the insert query.  You'll have to add `$result = mysqli_query(...` first, to check the insert query handling.

Comment: So I found the issue. My error was in the following fields:

Comment: Which fields? It appears that your last comment was cut short.

Comment: My edit took too long... 

So I found the issue. My error was in the following fields:

    `  //Insert the user into the database
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";`

I needed the user_ before the database field name to match my database values.

Comment: You fixed the first of my two issues. You lead me to the second answer as well. I greatly appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Did the error check help point that out?  If so, keep that handling in mind, so that you can let the program tell you what is wrong -- especially when working with the DB. With PHP, you can use either `var_dump($var)` or `print_r($var)` to see the contents of variables, even arrays.

Comment: If you could post one or both of your responses (with different strings in them) as an answer, we can close this out. You helped me locate the fields I was looking for so I would like that credit to go to you.

Comment: The error check did not propagate anything either time. I think it could have been where I placed it though so blame will fall on me. I was changing multiple fields with each attempt so I wasn't able to isolate where the issue was coming from.

Comment: The location redirects may have 'clobbered' any output that would have been displayed. I should have mentioned to temporarily comment those out in the query areas, OR I could have used `die` as shown in the answer below so that the script would show the message and then exit before the redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the connection handling, you can add this after the connect attempt:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( ... );

if ( !$conn ) {
    die( 'Did not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error() ); 
}
```

To check the handling after a query, you can add this after the query attempt:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

if (false === $result) {
    die( 'Query error: ' . mysqli_error($conn) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `php -l` right off the bat I found some errors in your code in the `includes/signup.inc.php` file.

The line `echo <h2>Please fill in all fields;` was not quoted which would cause an error 500 when I tried to load the page. To fix this I added single quotes `echo '<h2>Please fill in all fields</h2>';` and added `</h2>` to close the HTML tag.

After that was fixed the page would return **`Please fill in all fields`** even though I had filled all the fields in the sign up form. to fix this issue I changed `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['POST_DATA']);` to `strip_tags(trim($_POST['POST_DATA']));`.

The email line is a little bit different, `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);` is changed to `filter_var(trim($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));`

I also changed the `$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` (PHP Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) line to add salt. What is salt?

> In cryptography, a salt is random data that is used as an additional
>   input to a one-way function that "hashes" a password or passphrase.
>   Salts are closely related to the concept of nonce. The primary
>   function of salts is to defend against dictionary attacks or against
>   its hashed equivalent, a pre-computed rainbow table attack.

Source: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Also take a look at this post in stackexchange/security for some more information Link: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983

---

New `includes/signup.inc.php` file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
  $first = strip_tags(trim($_POST['first']));
  $last = strip_tags(trim($_POST['last']));
  $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
  $uid = strip_tags(trim($_POST['uid']));
  $pwd = strip_tags(trim($_POST['pwd']));
  //Error handlers
  //Check for empty fields
  if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    echo '<h2>Please fill in all fields</h2>'; // was echo <h2>Please fill in all fields; which would cause an error 500
    exit ();
  }
  else {
    //Check if input characters are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
      exit();
    }
    else {
      //Check if email is valid
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
        exit();
      }
      else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
          exit();
        }
        else {
          //Hashing the password
          $options = [
            'cost' => 12,
          ];
          $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options); // Adding salt to hashed password
          //Insert the user into the database
          $sql = "
                    INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, uid, pwd)
                    VALUES ('" . $first . "', 
                    '" . $last . "', 
                    '" . $email . "', 
                    '" . $uid . "', 
                    '" . $hashedPwd . "');";
          mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
else {
  header("Location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

In addition it would be a good idea to learn how to use the OOP style of `mysqli` to do more complex database manipulation

PHP Documentation on mysqli: php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

It would also be good to add a column to act as a serial number to allow later editing of values for the users using this MySQL Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `serial` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```